# Existence of sequence of polynomials such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 |h(x) - p_n(x)|^2 dx = 0$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

For a function $h:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$: 
$$h(x) = \begin{cases} 1~~\text{for}~~ x\in[0, \frac12] \\0 ~~\text{for}~~ x\in(\frac12, 1] \end{cases}$$

how could we prove the existence of sequence of polynomials $(p_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 |h(x) - p_n(x)|^2 dx = 0$ holds?

I was thinking of something similar to Weierstrauss approximation theorem but it required $h$ to be continuous function which in our case isn't.

Comment: By your observation, it seems it suffices to approximate $h$ by a continuous function. Can you do that?

Comment: @clark Would Fourier series be it?

Comment: you can do that using theorems from Fourier analysis, or you can draw a picture and  try to see how you can approximate the graph in a convenient way. To avoid this kind of approximation you can see my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $$f_n(x) = 
\begin{array}[cc]
11 ,& x<1/2 \\
(3/2-x)^n, & 1/2\leq x\leq 1
\end{array}$$

Notice that $|f_n(x)| \leq 1$ and that $f_n \rightarrow h$ pointwise.

Now observe that $|h-f_n|^2 \leq 4$ so by dominated convergence 
$$\lim _n\int _0 ^1 |h-f_n|^2 d x\rightarrow 0.$$

Now use your idea by approximating $f_n$ by a polynomial $|f_n(x) - p_n(x)| < \epsilon$.

And deduce that $$\lim _n\int _0 ^1 |h-p_n|^2 d x\rightarrow 0.$$

It would be useful to remember this inequality $ |a-b|^2 \leq 2(a^2 +b^2)$

Comment: small  typo $|f_n - p_n| < \frac{1}{n}|$

Answer (score 0):

You could try approximating the sequence $h_n$ where $h_n$ is $h$, except it goes from 1 to 0 continuously (say linearly) on the interval $(1/2-\epsilon_n,1/2+\epsilon_n)$ where $\epsilon_n \to 0$.

Let $\lVert \cdot \rVert^2 = \int_0^1 (\cdot)$

Then, use triangle inequality to note $\lVert h-p_n \rVert = \lVert h-h_n + h_n-p_n \rVert \leq \lVert h-h_n \rVert + \lVert h_n-p_n \rVert$.

Since $\epsilon_n \to 0$, $\lVert h-h_n \rVert \to 0$. Then, by picking the sequence $p_n$ to approximate $h_n$ to the desired precision (which you can do by Weirestrass approximation, say to tolerance $\frac{1}{n}$), you can make second term go to zero and thus $\lVert h-p_n \rVert \to 0$ as desired.